# ¿Como llamar a una función después que se ejecute una función de datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Quiero ejecurtar una funcion para realizar x acción despues de realizar una busqueda, mostrar datos o despues de usar la paginación de DataTable  pero no se como hacerlo 
alguien me puede ayudar ? 
Muestro el codigo que me lista los datos

```js
table = $('#table').DataTable({
  "scrollX": true,
  "scrollY": "245px",
  "lengthMenu": [
    [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, -1],
    [5, 15, 25, 50, 100, "Todo"]
  ],
  "scrollCollapse": false,
  "ordering": false,
  "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
  "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
  "order": [], //Initial no order.
  "language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados en su busqueda",
    "searchPlaceholder": "Buscar registros",
    "info": "Mostrando  de _START_ al _END_  de  _TOTAL_ registros",
    "infoEmpty": "No existen registros",
    "infoFiltered": "",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "processing": "Procesando...:",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Último",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    },
  },
  // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
  "ajax": {
    "url": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>planilla/ajax_list",
    "type": "POST"
  },
  //Set column definition initialisation properties.
  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": [-1, -44, -43], //last column
    "orderable": false, //set not orderable
  }, ],

});
```

tabla con datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table').DataTable().on("draw", function(){
    //Funcion
})
```

El evento draw se ejecuta despues de que se pinta la tabla

Comment: añadiendo eso podre llamar a otra funcion ?Edito la funcion o es aparte?

Comment: Exacto dentro podras llamar a la funcion que necesites o la accion que desees despues de realizar busqueda, paginacion o mostrar datos ya que esas aciones pintan la tabla y el eevento draw se ejecuta